# Dynamic allocation of memory within the given array

Tags: acegen

Let say a have an array of known dimension array={-1, 3, 6, -5, -6, 12} and indexes where the negative numbers appear is not known in advance. I want to create an array for which elements satisfy array[[i]]>0 which dimension is of course not known in advance. Is it possible in AceGen? There is the SMSRealList function but I don't know if there is possible or how to use If statement inside.

Comment: Can you give a bit more context as to what this has to do with AceGen? I would have said `Select[array, Positive]` does what you want - but that has nothing to do with AceGen, so am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Comment: Thanks Syed, I referred hovewer to AceGen which is a package for mathematica with own special functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With varaiable length arrays, you can operate with `SMSArray[array,maxNoIndices,function]` to define your `array`, in the 3rd argument one can place a `Function` argument which should contain instruction to create entry values for you (e.g. import from field, or copy, or any function of `i`). Note that `maxNoIndices` has to be specified, it should have little effect on efficiency of your code, only actual no of entries should have, but if the array has to be stored within the code it will influence the code size it has to allocate.

To acces `i`-th entry form array `SMSArray` or any Mathematica List, where index `i` is unknown use `SMSPart[array,i]`.

To modify entries one can use to `array\[DoubleRightTee]SMSReplacePart[array,i->newValue]`. The `array` has to be owerwritten.

Below is a simple Mathlink code that does what you ask. You can use it within any code, but then just make sure to modify your Function to specify where to fill the SMSArray from and Import/Export arguments as per your requirement. Output is the list of positive numbers and its length.

```
<< AceGen`;
nMax = 200;
SMSInitialize["test", "Environment" -> "MathLink"];
SMSModule["makeList1", Integer[lin$$[nMax], lout$$[nMax], n$$, npos$$],
"Input" -> {lin$$, n$$}, "Output" -> {lout$$, npos$$}];

(*Reading no of actual entries*)
n \[RightTee] SMSInteger[n$$];
(*Reading from input with unknown length...listIn is not physicaly an Array but Symbol representing one!!!*)
SMSArray[listIn, nMax, Function[{i}, SMSInteger[lin$$[i]]]];

(*Generating empty array which contains 0 entries*)
listOut \[DoubleLeftTee] SMSArray[nMax, "Type" -> Integer];
(*Set positive counter to 0*)
npos \[DoubleLeftTee] SMSInteger[0];
SMSDo[i, 1, n, 1, {npos, listOut}];
el \[DoubleRightTee] SMSPart[listIn, i];
SMSIf[el > 0,
  (*If i-th entry of listIn positive, increase npos and insert value to list*)
  npos \[LeftTee] npos + 1; 
  listOut \[LeftTee] 
SMSReplacePart[listOut, SMSInteger[npos] -> el];
];
SMSEndDo[{npos, listOut}];

(*Exporting *)
SMSDo[i, 1, npos];
    el = SMSPart[listOut, i];
    SMSExport[el, lout$$[i]];
SMSEndDo[];

(*Without exporting 0, entries AFTER npos can contain random entries...*)
SMSDo[i, npos + 1, nMax];
    SMSExport[0, lout$$[i]];
SMSEndDo[];

(*Export no of positive entries*)
SMSExport[npos, npos$$];

SMSWrite[];

SMSInstallMathLink[];

(*Run the generated code in Mathematica*)
nElements = 50;
listIn = PadRight [RandomInteger[{-20, 50}, nElements], nMax, 0]
listOut = PadRight [{}, nMax, 0];
makeList1[listIn, nElements]
Count[listIn, _?(# > 0 &)]
```

Alternatively one can use `SMSVerbatim` command and write manually that part of code directly in C or Fortran or MAtlab..., but this depends on the language you are using.

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation, but is it possible to retrieve the list in a table form and than do some calculation?  When elements of listOut are known and the length is npos my guess would be that Table[SMSPart[listOut,i], {i,npos}] should create "explicit" list but it does not work, is there other way or exporting is the only option?

Comment: If you want to generate code AceGen you can only operate with "explicit" lists of fixed length. Because you don't know in advance what `npos`, `SMSDo` is needed to make operations on arrays, index by index, which is always doable. You can make explicit list as: `listOut= SMSInteger[Table[0, {i, nMax}]]` and then use `Table` to fill it in, leaving 0 where negative terms appear, but this means `listOut` will always be `nMax` long and unsorted, so you can operate on it but it will be less efficient. If you need an `npos` long list with variable length you need to run the code in mathematica.